# Watch and reload api folder in Vue Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How to make nuxt watch for "non standard" directories and recompile / reload itself, and more specifically for dirs with additional server apis?

I have my express api in `~/api/`. Since I reference the directory in `serverMiddleware` with '~/api', I would expect Nuxt to reload when I make some changes to the files in that dir, but it doesn't.

I'm simply using npm run dev that fires nuxt, I don't have any direct control on either **nodemon** (if it's used internally) or on **webpack** (that I'm pretty sure is). I tried adding `watch: [ '~/api/*.js']`, `watch: [ '~/api/index.js']`, `watch: [ '~/api/**/*.js']` to build in `nuxt.conf.js` but with no luck.

Comment: found any good solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `watch: ['api/**/*.js']` or `watch: ['api']`.

Contrary to what the docs show custom paths in `build.watch` are not normalized via `Nuxt.resolveAlias()`, which means that Nuxt prefixes like `~` and `@` are not replaced by the actual paths.
Further down the line, when the watchers get created via chokidar, the checked path will still be "~/api" (which doesn't exist).

Bug report: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2983

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nodemon` to watch for changes inside your api folder. First install:

> npm install --save-dev nodemon

or:

> yarn add nodemon --dev

Then add this code inside of your `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --watch api --exec \"nuxt\"",
  },
}
```