# Nuxt js restart server on api folder changes

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In  my nuxt js application, I am trying to restart the server files which is in the `api` folder when a file changes.

In order to that, I've added the following to `nuxt.config.js`

```
build: {
    watch: ["~/api/index.js"]

}
```

When I make the changes on the files in API folder server doesn't restarted automatically

I've tried this thread [Watch and reload api folder in Vue Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653714/watch-and-reload-api-folder-in-vue-nuxt?rq=1) looks similar to my problem but it doesn't worked for me

Comment: maybe ["~/api/*.js"] is enough

Comment: @ducmai its not  worked

Comment: me too. did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested here
[Watch and reload api folder in Vue Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653714/watch-and-reload-api-folder-in-vue-nuxt?rq=1)

just adding

```
watch: ['api'],
```

to nuxt.config.js, at the root level, worked for me. Not under `build`, as you had it.

EDIT

Bizarrely, although I now see the server (and client, for some reason) being started in the console... the new code is not taken! So, that's fairly useless.
The only way to get the code changes is still to ctrl-C and restart from zero.

Comment: it's working well for me, not sure why you edited this so

Comment: i had to make the nuxt.config.js to watch a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I use nodemon.json config

```
{
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": ["node_modules", "dist"],
    "watch": [
      "app.js"
    ],
    "ext": "js json"
  }
```